# Слитно/раздельно, запятая

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Добрый день! Как правильно написать?
Мы выезжаем к заказчику не зависимо где расположен его офис.

Answer (score 3):

> Как правильно написать?

Так:

*Мы выезжаем к заказчику **независимо от того,** где расположен его офис.*

Answer (score 0):

Да, ответ верный.  Это особый тип предложений (СПП), нечто среднее между изъяснительными и местоименными придаточными (иногда их называют **изъяснительными вмещающими**).

Характерная особенность  таких предложений (по сравнению с обычными изъяснительными) - это **обязательное наличие указательного слова**, содержание которого и раскрывает придаточное предложение.
Мы выезжаем к заказчику независимо **от того**,  где расположен его офис.